# How to add success and failure handlers to this snippet?

Tags: android

I am using a snippet from a sample app using Nearby:

```
public void startAdvertising() {
    // Note: Advertising may fail. To keep this demo simple, we don't handle failures.
    connectionsClient.startAdvertising(
            "Tester", getPackageName(), connectionLifecycleCallback,
            new AdvertisingOptions.Builder().setStrategy(STRATEGY).build());
}
```

How do I change this code to have both "on success" and "on failure" handlers as shown in the Nearby website:

```
private void startAdvertising() {
  Nearby.getConnectionsClient(context).startAdvertising(
          getUserNickname(),
          SERVICE_ID,
          mConnectionLifecycleCallback,
          new AdvertisingOptions(STRATEGY))
      .addOnSuccessListener(
        new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Void unusedResult) {
            // We're advertising!
          }
        })
      .addOnFailureListener(
        new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // We were unable to start advertising.
          }
        });
  }
```

I don't know how to change the first snippet to make it work like the second, because it looks like the code used in the website is slightly different (maybe an older API?) So I don't know how to make it work so that I start advertising but also add the success/failure handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
connectionsClient.startAdvertising(
        "Tester", getPackageName(), connectionLifecycleCallback,
        new AdvertisingOptions.Builder().setStrategy(STRATEGY).build())
    .addOnSuccessListener(
        new OnSuccessListener < Void > () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccess...");
            }
        }
    )
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OnFailure 1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```